# Location sharing is not enabled on my device. How do I fix that?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, samsung-galaxy-s-21

When I try to share my location in Google Maps on my Samsung Galaxy S21 FE, I get the following error message:

[image: screen shot]

Roughly translated, the error message means "Location sharing is not enabled on this device". Next to it is a link labeled "Beheben", which means "Fix it". When I click on that link, the link is replaced with a spinner for about 1 second, then the "Fix it" link just reappears, and nothing else happens.

**Why is Google Maps unable to fix the problem, and how can I fix it myself?** The issue seems somehow related to my Google account, since I *can* share my location when logging in to Maps with another Google account.

What I already tried:

- Check my Google account settings: Everything there looks fine to me.
- "Send feedback" to Google: Done (at least) twice in the last months. No reply.
- Ask on the Google community forum. Won't work. (More or less) the same message as in this question here results in *"Failed to post. Content violates Community Policy."*